# How to get the shortest line between two polygons in R

Tags: r, distance, r-sf

I'm using `st_distance()` in the R package sf to compute the distance between two polygons. I'd like to also get the shortest line between the polygons, i.e. the line along which the distance is obtained. Is there any easy way to do this ?

Comment: `sf::st_nearest_points()`   https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_nearest_points.html

Comment: @mrhellmann, thanks a million times, that's exactly what I need !